# Getting the containers for the app's settings and files in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8

I'm trying to get  containers for my app settings and files and i found this code in Microsoft Website

```
Windows.Storage.ApplicationDataContainer localSettings = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
Windows.Storage.ApplicationDataContainer localFolder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
```

but when i paste it to my code it give me an Error

[image]

anyone know what is the error ? how can i solve it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LocalFolder isn't a storage container, its a storage folder.  Wouldn't something like this work better?

Windows.Storage.ApplicationDataContainer localSettings =    Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;

Windows.Storage.StorageFolder localFolder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;

Answer (score 0):

The property you are accessing returns an object of type `StorageFolder` (as documented on the same MS webpage where you found an incorrect example). So, just change the type of `localFolder` as appropriate.

Don't trust examples, they often contain errors for the first several years after publishing. Also, learn to read and understand error messages. The error you posted explicitly says what's wrong and how to fix it.